# How can I get the previous and current count of the Transaction in efficient way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `[SourceTbl]` and `[TransactionDates]`.. In my `SourceTbl` I have these fields.. `Source` and `Transaction`

**SourceTbl Table:**

```
[Source]  [Transaction]   
 AAB        1  
 AAA        1  
 ABB        2  
 AAA        1  
 AAB        1
```

**TransactionDates Table:**

```
 [TransactionID] [Date]    [isActive]  
     1           9/26/2014   1  
     2           9/25/2014   0  
     3           9/24/2014   0
```

If we choose the `TransactionID` need to count the current Transaction selected and also get the previous count on the previous Transaction (-1 date or row of active transaction). Transactions is base what is Active. Only 1 active date should be activated in the table.
Output should be - The `TransactionID` I used is 1.

```
Source PrevCount CurrentCount   
 AAB     0          2   
 AAA     0          2  
 ABB     1          0
```

Comment: What do `PrevCount` and `CurrentCount` mean? Transactions yesterday and today?

Comment: Yes... you're correct

Comment: -1 row or date are not the same if there is a skipped date or duplicate date.  Question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbb69/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [SourceTbl] ([Source] VARCHAR(10),  [Transaction] INT)
INSERT INTO [SourceTbl]([Source] ,[Transaction]) 
VALUES
('AAB', 1),
('AAA', 1),
('ABB', 2),
('AAA', 1),
('AAB', 1)

CREATE TABLE [TransactionDates] ([TransactionID] INT,  [Date]  DATE)
INSERT INTO [TransactionDates] ([TransactionID], [Date])
VALUES     
(1 ,'9/26/2014'),
(2 ,'9/25/2014'),
(3 ,'9/24/2014')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT S.Source
      ,COUNT( CASE WHEN T.[Date] = CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS DATE) 
                                          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PrevCount 
      ,COUNT( CASE WHEN T.[Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
                                          THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CurrentCount
FROM SourceTbl S 
INNER JOIN TransactionDates T ON S.[Transaction] = T.[TransactionID]
WHERE T.[DATE] >= CAST(GETDATE() - 1 AS DATE)
 AND  T.[DATE] <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
GROUP BY S.Source
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbb69/1/0)**:

```
| SOURCE | PREVCOUNT | CURRENTCOUNT |
|--------|-----------|--------------|
|    AAA |         0 |            2 |
|    AAB |         0 |            2 |
|    ABB |         1 |            0 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution. Currently I'm not dealing with the current date. It depends on the Transaction that is Active.

Comment: And what makes a transaction Active or InActive ? Well you need to provide all the information to get a porper solution, you cant expect anyone here to guess what you want.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the all the information. I already modified the parent topic. 

Added the IsActive field in the TransactionDates table so we can toggle what I want to monitor the changes

Comment: Now Active Rows are CURRENTCOUNT  and InActive rows are PREVCOUNT  ?

Comment: For the previous transaction. Just only -1 row or date of active transaction